# How to deal with a string with comma in it from a csv, when we have to read the data by using loadrunner?

Tags: csv, loadrunner

When I used Loadrunner, it can read data from a `csv` file. As we know , `csv` file is separated by a comma.

The question is, if the parameter in `csv` has comma itself, the string will be separated to several segments. That is not I want to get.

How can we get the original data with comma in it?

Answer (score 1):

When data has a comma, use an escape character to store the data in the parameter.
For example, if the name is 'Smith, John', it can be stored as Smith\, John in the Loadrunner data file.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file in Excel that has commas in the actual cell data, the whole cell will be inside two " characters. Also it seems that cells with a space in them are inside " chars.

Example

```
ColA,ColB,"ColC with a , inside",ColD,ColE
```

More info on CSV file format: http://www.parse-o-matic.com/parse/pskb/CSV-File-Format.htm

The answer to the question is that perhaps the easiest way to do deal with , separators is to change the separator to a **;** character. This is also a valid separator in CSV files.

Then the example would be:

```
ColA;ColB;"ColC with a , inside";ColD;ColE
```

Comment: As you say , I open a csv file in notepad ,and change the separator "," to ";". GD_BH_NX,广东1楼备货区（内销）,备货区  After the replacing , I open the file by excel again,the data would be:GD_BH_NX;广东1楼备货区（内销);备货区 and  the  string go into a grid.

Comment: BTW, how can I end a line...   I use two spaces and a "<br/>"  but it doesnt work....     test  <br/> line 2  line 3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the right way is to use C functions to read data from the file (for example fopen/fread)? When you have read it you be able to use "strchr" to find first quotes char and second quotes char. All in that interval would be a value, and it doesn't matter if comma is inside.
For the documentation about fopen, fread,strchr, you could refer to the HP or C function references.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is incorrect for LoadRunner.   The built in parameter engine takes care of all of the file management.   As a point of fact, at the beginning of the test all parameter files are loaded into RAM in order to avoid disk activity during the test which would slow the virtual users avoiding disk contention with dozens or hundreds of threads reading from the disk.    The Parameterization engine also allows for a custom seperator, so while comma is the default you can use another symbol which would be distinct for your data set.

Comment: Oh.. I misunderstood question. I didn't see word parameter and thought about reading custom csv file instead of parameters file.

Comment: thx for your answer , this is my first time to use the website. maybe I didnt describe the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading from a data file for the parameters, just use a custom seperator.   Comma is the default, but you can define it to be whatever you want.   Whenever I have a comma in the variable data I tend to use a pipe symbol, '|' as a way to distinguish the columns of data in the data file.

Examine your parameter dialog carefully and you will see where to make the change.