# Upload csv files with comma inside it

Tags: file-upload, loadrunner, vugen

As per my requirement, I need to upload a .csv file into the application. I am trying to simulate this using loadrunner. The issue I am encoutering is that my csv file is in the below format

Header - AA,BB,CC

Data-xyz,"yyx,zzy",xxz

On using the below statement to upload the file, I am getting an error ""line 2 contains 4 columns instead of 3"

```
web_submit_data("upload",
"Action=xxx/upload",
"Method=POST",
"EncType=multipart/form-data",
"RecContentType=text/html",
"Referer=xxx",
"Snapshot=t86.inf",
"Mode=HTML",
ITEMDATA,
"Name=utf8", "Value=âœ“", ENDITEM,
"Name=token", "Value={token_1}", ENDITEM,
"Name=upload_file", "Value={NewParam_5}", "File=yes",   "ContentType=text/csv", ENDITEM,
"Name=Button1", "Value=Upload", ENDITEM,
LAST);
```

AS per information provided in [How to deal with a string with comma in it from a csv, when we have to read the data by using loadrunner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793718/how-to-deal-with-a-string-with-comma-in-it-from-a-csv-when-we-have-to-read-the) , 
I tried updating the .prm file to a new delimiter pipe, | but still i get the error.

```
[parameter:NewParam_5]
Delimiter="|"
ParamName="NewParam_5"
TableLocation="C:\temp"
ColumnName="Col 1"
```

I also notice that even though I set the delimiter to pipe, if I rightclick on the web_submit_data() and go to Parameter properties, i see a column delimiter option there as well and it is not set to pipe and is set to comma which indicates that this setting is taking higher precedence to the setting in .prm file.

Can someone please guide me the right way to set a new delimiter so that vugen recognizes and parses the csv file as I want it to.

I am using loadrunner 12.5

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to upload a file or a line of comma separated variables?   Right now you appear to be reading a line of CSV variables, not a file as your parameter file would contain a list of filenames or a single file reference within the directory of the virtual user (extra files, transferred with the use) or created by the virtual user and then uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for responding James.. I would need to upload a csv file.. Initially the event that was recorded had a file name Value="{C:\\test\\sample.csv}" but on right clicking the content and selecting 'Show Arguments', Parameter properties was displayed where in there was a .dat file that was not currently used. I used it to make sure I follow the paramterization process that we follow normally which changed the Value in event(as shown in original post) but i found no luck even by doing that. My intention here is to upload the file.

Comment: Looks like you were on the wrong path by providing the content of the file rather than the filename itself.   Take a representative file, place it inside of the virtual user directory.  Be sure to include this as an extra file for distribution with the virtual user.  Then change the filename to that actual filename.   You can make the decision later on whether you are going to upload files from a different common location to the load generator virtual users or whether you will build the file dynamically.  But as it stands now you are semantically on the wrong path with the content of the file

Comment: This actually worked James. Thank you for the directions. web_submit_data("upload",
  "Action=www.sample.com/upload",
  "Method=POST",
  "EncType=multipart/form-data",
  "Referer=www.sample.com/login",
  "Snapshot=t101.inf",
  "Mode=HTML",
  ITEMDATA,
  "Name=utf8", "Value=âœ“", ENDITEM,
  "Name=token", "Value={token}", ENDITEM,
  "Name=upload_file", "Value=sample.csv", "File=yes", ENDITEM,
  LAST);

Comment: Also I am able to achieve parameterization by doing this  Name=upload_file_{UserId}

Comment: Glad you found a resolution.  Thank you for posting the resolution for those researching the issue in the future